# How to resolve this typescript error on global node.js object

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I am following this guide https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres to create a full stack app. Typescript is throwing an error in this snippet of code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```

TypeScript is throwing a `ts7017` on the `global.prisma`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
```

Can someone help me understand this and how to fix? I set 'strict' to false in the tsconfig for the meantime and that supressed the issue for the meantime, though I'm sure having it off defeats the purpose of TS.

Comment: Do you know how `global.prisma` is declared?
If you don't have access to its declaration, have you tried casting it with `global.prisma as PrismaClient`?

Comment: I would just not use the global..    It's not even clear why there doing that in the first place..  strange!!!  They even import later. `import prisma from '../lib/prisma';`

Comment: Nikolas from the Prisma team here! We recommend the instantiation of `PrismaClient` in this way because otherwise the DB connection limit gets exhausted in development due to Next.js' hot reloading. Here's our docs page about this: https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices I'm checking back with some of our TypeScript engineers to see how this issue can be solved.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I could reproduce the same error with strict mode to true and `@types/node` package version 16

Update: see the other answer recommended from the docs here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69851359/1345244

This should work:

```
declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient; // This must be a `var` and not a `let / const`
}

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```

Comment: i was trying the same but i was adding const instead of let. i am confused why it didnt worked with const?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices#solution) you need to declare the variable `global` first:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined
}

export const prisma =
  global.prisma ||
  new PrismaClient({
    log: ['query'],
  });

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') global.prisma = prisma;
```

You can also have a separate file `globals.d.ts` with the declaration in it.

Comment: Can you explain a little more the purpose of writing the | undefined ?

Comment: The pipe in this case is used to separate the different types the variable *prisma* can potentially be. By adding ‘| undefined’ typescript will warn if the variable is used without checking if it’s defined.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and helping me understand :)